# Wireframe helper and edges in three.js

Tags: three.js, edges, wireframe

In three.js if I use the wireframe helper or individually add a line representing the edge at the intersection of two faces the line is visible from one side of the intersection but not visible from the other side.

I would expect the wireframe line to be visible from both sides. Any idea how to make it?

Comment: Can you put a image up of what you are seeing?

Comment: I can't upload images yet, but here is a link where you can see the phenomenon:
http://edg3d.io/embed.php?e=A4HTDSZ3k0XFD2m&p=0&fullscreen=1

Answer (score 0):

```
    var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.WireframeGeometry(geometry));
    wireframe.material.depthTest = false;
    wireframe.material.opacity = 0.25;
    wireframe.material.transparent = true;
```

Comment: You should give more context to an answer rather than just dropping a block of code that the OP or future readers may not understand

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.